# Fix repeated keystrokes on Windows

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

My keyboard have this problem that sometimes it registers two keypresses, doubling a key. So I am trying to fix it using software.

I solved it by going to Ease of Access Center and enabling Filter Keys > Bounce Keys, and set the delay to 50 milliseconds (The lowest setting there is 0.5s or 500ms, but I changed to 50 using registry and it worked).

This solved my problem but now when I hold down a key, it doesn't repeat anymore.

I tried solving this using Repeat Keys/Slow Keys, but it didn't work.

Anyone could help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question was right on the registry (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\Keyboard Response) : AutoRepeatDelay and AutoRepeatRate were set to 0, so I set to the values I wanted (in ms) and it worked after Logout/Logon.

Comment: It is also relevant to mention the BounceTime setting which is an int given ms. e.g. 35 = 35ms.

Comment: Also bought a new keyboard ;)